# Не получается сделать передачу универсальной ссылки в std::multiset

Tags: c++, visual-studio, шаблоны-с++, c++14, std-forward

Решил попробовать сделать передачу в `std::set` и написал следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::multiset;

multiset<string> storage{};

template<typename T>
void AddNameInStorage(T&& in_name) {
    storage.emplace(std::forward(in_name));
    //cout << in_name;
};

int main(){
    string tmp{ "aaa" };
    AddNameInStorage(tmp);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу скомпилировать, компилятор выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> error C2672: 'std::multiset,std::allocator<_Kty>>::emplace': no matching overloaded function found
>   with
>   [
>   _Kty=std::string
>   ]

Хоть убей, не могу понять что не так. Как мне исправить код что бы это заработало?

С++ 14, компилятор MSVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
storage.emplace(std::forward<T>(in_name));
```

Comment: >_<, спасибо =)